# Problems creating random path for tower defense game

Tags: java

I am having difficulty figuring out how one might go about creating a randomly generated path for the entities, using the following set of classes I've written below.

I understand this is a very specific issue and there are many ways one might go about programmatically creating the solution that's right for the game.

So, with that said, I can give you context as to what type of game I am trying to create.

**GameType: Tower Defense**

If you would like to see my own attempt at the solution, see below:

**generateWorld():**

```
    public void generateWorld() {
        String worldCode = Util.generateCode(8);
        TinyDebug.debug("World", "Generating [gameWorld] w/ [worldCode]: " + worldCode);

        worldWidth = new Random().nextInt(256);
        worldHeight = new Random().nextInt(256);
        xSpawn = new Random().nextInt(10);
        ySpawn = xSpawn;

        /*
        TinyDebug.debug("worldWidth", worldWidth);
        TinyDebug.debug("worldHeight", worldHeight);
        TinyDebug.debug("xSpawn", xSpawn);
        TinyDebug.debug("ySpawn", ySpawn);
        */

        worldMap = new int[worldWidth][worldHeight];
        for (int xPos = 0; xPos < worldWidth; xPos++) {
            for (int yPos = 0; yPos < worldHeight; yPos++) {
                int randomValue = new Random().nextInt(2);
                switch (randomValue) {
                case 0:
                    worldMap[xPos][yPos] = Tile.grassTile.getID();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    worldMap[xPos][yPos] = Tile.dirtTile.getID();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    worldMap[xPos][yPos] = Tile.stoneTile.getID();
                    break;
                default:
                    worldMap[xPos][yPos] = Tile.grassTile.getID();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        TinyDebug.debug("World", "[gameWorld] w/ [worldCode]: " +  worldCode + " has been generated successfully.");
    }
```

As you can see, this current code, just randomly places tiles due to the random # that is generated.

However, my problem is more specific and complex. I don't know how one might go about creating the path for the entities to flow through. Mind you the path is randomly generated.

I know there are easier ways to do this, e.g. load from a file, but thought it would be fun if I could find out how to do it automatically.

**World.java:**

```
    public class World {
    private Game game;

    private int worldWidth, worldHeight, xSpawn, ySpawn;
    private int[][] worldMap;

    public World(Game game) { 
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void generateWorld() {
        //Method used to generate a random world. 
    }

    public void loadWorld(String filePath, String fileName, String fileExtension) {
        String worldFile = TinyFile.loadAppendedFile(filePath + fileName + fileExtension);
        String[] tokens = worldFile.split("\\s+");

        worldWidth = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        worldHeight = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        xSpawn = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
        ySpawn = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);

        TinyDebug.debug("worldWidth", worldWidth);
        TinyDebug.debug("worldHeight", worldHeight);
        TinyDebug.debug("xSpawn", xSpawn);
        TinyDebug.debug("ySpawn", ySpawn);

        worldMap = new int[worldWidth][worldHeight];
        for (int xPos = 0; xPos < worldWidth; xPos++) {
            for (int yPos = 0; yPos < worldHeight; yPos++) {
                worldMap[xPos][yPos] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[(xPos + yPos * worldWidth) + 4]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void update() {}

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        for (int xPos = 0; xPos < worldWidth; xPos++) {
            for (int yPos = 0; yPos < worldHeight; yPos++) {
                getTile(xPos, yPos).render(g, xPos * Tile.TILEWIDTH, yPos * Tile.TILEHEIGHT);
            }
        }
    }

    private Tile getTile(int xPos, int yPos) {
        return Tile.tilesArray[worldMap[xPos][yPos]];
    }

    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public int getxSpawn() {
        return xSpawn;
    }

    public int getySpawn() {
        return ySpawn;
    }
}
```

**Tile.java:**

```
    public class Tile {
    public static Tile[] tilesArray = new Tile[256];
    public static Tile grassTile = new GrassTile(0);
    public static Tile dirtTile = new DirtTile(1);
    public static Tile stoneTile = new StoneTile(2);

    public static final int TILEWIDTH = 64;
    public static final int TILEHEIGHT = 64;

    protected BufferedImage tileTexture;
    protected final int id;

    public Tile(BufferedImage tileTexture, int id) {
        this.tileTexture = tileTexture;
        this.id = id;

        tilesArray[id] = this;
    }

    public void update() {}

    public void render(Graphics g, int xPos, int yPos) {
        g.drawImage(tileTexture, xPos, yPos, TILEWIDTH, TILEHEIGHT, null);
    }

    public boolean isSolid() {
        return false;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**GrassTile.java:**

```
public class GrassTile extends Tile {
    public GrassTile(int id) {
        super(Library.grassTile, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: "randomly generated path" Can you be more specific? How do you want it to look? Straight lines? Curves? Vertical climbs? This question is both ambiguous and too broad.

Comment: @Krythic I would preferably want it to be straight lines either going from top to bottom or left to right.

Comment: So start from the unit/player's location, then advance in a random direction, check collision, advance again, check collision, up to the desired tile-move-length. Pretty straight forward concept.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you would do the above-mentioned programmatically, store the result in a List, then execute the movement by reading the list by index, moving by frame-time, turn, or warp all at once.

Comment: @Krythic okay awesome, thanks for your input!